# Generating different content for different tabs in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs

So I have a code that lets me generate tabs based on the user's input using a for loop.

```
var tabs = "";
var y = 1;
for (var x = 0; x < tabNum; x++) 
{
    tabs += "<li class = 'tabbers'>" + "<a href='#tab'>Tab</a>"  + "</li>"
}
document.write(tabs)
```

Now what I want to do is to generate contents for the tabs that I've created like for example, Tab 1 has the contents This is Tab 1 and Tab 2 has This is Tab 2. Any idea on how I could achieve this? All I managed to do was loop the contents in the tab and that's not what I wanted.

Comment: Are you saying you want to generate other, separate elements, one per tab, where clicking the link in the code you've shown would display the related element with relevant content?

Answer (score 0):

i think this can help you. i get from w3school example for use bootstrap 3.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Dynamic Tabs</h2>
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#menu1">Menu 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#menu2">Menu 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#menu3">Menu 3</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
      <h3>HOME</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Menu 1</h3>
      <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Menu 2</h3>
      <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="menu3" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Menu 3</h3>
      <p>Eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".nav-tabs a").click(function(){
        $(this).tab('show');
    });
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/df56fL56/

```js
$( function() {
  $('#tabs').append('<ul/>');
  for(var i=1; i<=3; i++){
    $('#tabs ul').append(`<li><a href="#tabs-${i}">Tab ${i}</a></li>`);
    $('#tabs').append(`<div id="tabs-${i}">
      <p>This is Tab ${i}</p>
    </div>`);
  }

  $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
});
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="tabs"></div>
```

This code will dynamically add `tabs`.

First append a `ul` then attach `li` to the `ul` over a loop & in the same loop attach the tab content as well.

I've used `ES6` `backtick` to append elements.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Use **Jquery**

```
$("#sub").on('click', function() {
    var tabNum = $('#in').val();
    var tabs = "";
    for (var x = 1; x <= tabNum; x++) {
        $('.app').append("<li class = 'tabbers'>" + "<a href='#tab'>This is Tab" + x + "</a>" + "</li>");
    }

});
```

Sample [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9pmqtkqq/1/)..